# Best way to xml to object using Kotlin fasterxml

Tags: xml, kotlin, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dataset id="infoList">
        <rows>
            <row>
                <lvl>4</lvl>
                <itemCd>9999</itemCsfCd>
                <itemName>HELLO</itemCsfNm>
                <itemPrice>50</itemPrice>
            </row>
        </rows>
    </Dataset>
    <Dataset id="result">
        <rows>
            <row>
                <code>0000</code>
                <message>Success</message>
            </row>
        </rows>
    </Dataset>
```

There are two  in different formats within the parent .
Each Dataset is distinguished by its id property.
I want to map this to an object using fasterxml.

I want to map it to

```
data class Response(
    val info: InfoDataset;

    val result: ResultDataset
)
```

not

```
data class Response(
    val datasetList: List<Dataset>
)
```

I tried

```
data class Response2XML(
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Dataset")
    val info: InfoDataset,

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Dataset")
    val result: ResultDataset
)
```

But Conflicting getter definitions for property "Dataset" error occured.

How do i solve this problem?

Comment: Jackson (fasterxml) is a *Java* library. Since you are using *Kotlin*, it might be nicer to use a library built for it, such as `kotlinx.serialization`. Having said that, it's certainly *possible* to do this with Jackson.

Comment: @Jorn The problem is that there are multiple <Dataset> in XML.
The name is <Dataset>, but since the internal fields are different, I want to distinguish them by the id property of <Dataset id="dsList">, but if I use @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Dataset"), a conflict error occurs because they are two identical datasets. no see.

Comment: Yes, XML that's structured like that can be difficult to parse correctly. I don't have much experience with the XML side of Jackson, so I can't help you there.

Comment: that's right. It's a crappy data format. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Perhaps you can parse it to a DTO structure that's as close to the XML as possible, then map it to a different set of of objects later.

Comment: _"Jackson (fasterxml) is a Java library."_ Jackson has excellent integration with Kotlin, and a rich feature set. In my opinion, the primary reason to use `kotlinx.serialization` over Jackson is if your target is multi-platform.